# how to get a linkedhashmap value using index?

Tags: java, android

i'm new to java.. i've made a linked hashmap like :

```
Map<String, Double> MonthlyCPIMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
        MonthlyCPIMenu.put("1394/10", 0.0);
        MonthlyCPIMenu.put("1394/09", 231.6);
        MonthlyCPIMenu.put("1394/08", 228.7);
        MonthlyCPIMenu.put("1394/07", 227.0);
        MonthlyCPIMenu.put("1394/06", 225.7);
```

I know how to find each item's index using (for example):

```
String duemonth="1394/08";
            int indexduemonth = new ArrayList<String>(MonthlyCPIMenu.keySet()).indexOf(duemonth);
```

but I don't know how to find the value using index. (I know how to get the value using key but in this case i should use index for some reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crude way to do it would be

```
new ArrayList<String>(MonthlyCPIMenu.keySet()).get(index);
```

but `LinkedHashMap` generally doesn't support efficient indexed retrieval, and it doesn't provide any API for the purpose.  The best algorithm to do it is just to take `MonthlyCPIMenu.keySet().iterator()`, call `next()` `index` times, and then return the result of one final `next()`:

```
<K, V> K getKey(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map, int index) {
    Iterator<K> itr = map.keySet().iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        itr.next();
    }
    return itr.next();
}
```

Comment: @mdehghani, here you are.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have a specific reason you are using a LinkedHashMap?  Generally speaking, iterating over keys is cheap and lookups are 0(1).  Why does order of the values matter?

You can retrieve values from a map using the get(key) method.

```
Map.get(key);
```

You can protect against nulls with:

```
Map.get(key) != null ? Map.get(key) : "";
```

This will return the value if the key is found, else return an empty string.  You can replace the empty string with whatever you want.

Comment: James B:the reason is that i'm using this map related to a spinner and i need the next row that a user chooses, and i think the only way is to find the index and get the value of (index+1).

Comment: James B: the method you have provided seems to solely retrieve the value based on key and returns null if I insert the index

Comment: Correct, that is how you get a value out of a key,value pair.  If you want to protect against nulls then do: Map.get(key) != null ? Map.get(key) : "";

Comment: thx. but that is not the answer of my question. keys are different from indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on getting the value then use the List interface and create your own type

```
public class MyValue {
String date;
String value;

public MyValue(String d, String v) {
    this.date = d;
    this.value = v;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

}

Then use the List interface:

```
List<MyValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
// put all you values in the list
// get the values out by index in the list
```