# ArrayMap alternative preserving insertion order and has methods get() and valueAt()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-structures

This is for Android Studio Java. I was using an `ArrayMap` because I both need the methods `get(Object key)` and `valueAt(int index)`.
But an `ArrayMap` doesn't preserve the insertion order.

So I tried a `LinkedHashMap` because that preserves the insertion order. But a `LinkedHashMap` doesn't have the `valueAt(int index)` method.

Is there a Map that preserves the insertion order and has both the methods `get(Object key)` and `valueAt(int index)`?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first post!

First, a word of advice - this isn't so much an Android issue as it is a Java issue, so while tagging this question with Android may gain it more visibility, it's a bit of a mislabelling.

Second, if you are tagging Java, you can also try to tag the particular Java version (Java 6/7/8 etc) which should be found in your `build.gradle` file...

Third, please make sure you are searching, and making sure that you are reviewing SO's suggested similar questions, as most items, such as this one, have been asked & answered before...

---

As for your question, there isn't a single instance of the Map class tree that has indexable methods. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html and it's descendants... also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html.

However, the Apache Commons library has an implementation of a LinkedMap that does have a `indexOf()` method... though that may be heavyweight to add for such a use case?

There are ways to do this by yourself however, mainly which involve forcing that by wrapping/unwrapping into other data structures, and they tend to be inefficient (`O(n)`)...

Here are some posts about this:

- [how to get a linkedhashmap value using index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698751/how-to-get-a-linkedhashmap-value-using-index)
- [fetching from LinkedHashMap HashMap based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887378/fetching-from-linkedhashmap-hashmap-based-on-index)
- [How get value from LinkedHashMap based on index not on key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581997/how-get-value-from-linkedhashmap-based-on-index-not-on-key)
- [How to get position of key/value in LinkedHashMap using its key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387290/how-to-get-position-of-key-value-in-linkedhashmap-using-its-key)

As you can see, performance and verbosity are both potential issues here...

I guess the best thing would be to push back and see if you can clarify the use-case here, so that we can help determine what problem you are trying to solve exactly...